# prestashop se detiene cuando la conexión a la base de datos externa no es exitosa

Tags: mysql, mysqli, prestashop1.7

Tengo este hook donde se conecta a una base de datos. Cuando la conexión es exitosa, funciona bien. Pero cuando falla la conexión no me deja entrar a la página principal. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que prestashop continúe aunque haya un error en la conexión a la base de datos?

```
public function hookHeader() {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . '/views/js/front.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path . '/views/css/front.css');
        
        $database = Configuration::get('MIMODULOMISMADB_ACCOUNT_NOMBREDB', null);
        $user = Configuration::get('MIMODULOMISMADB_ACCOUNT_USUARIO', null);
        $password = Configuration::get('MIMODULOMISMADB_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD', null);
        try {
            $db = new DbMySQLi("localhost", $user, $password, $database, true);
        } catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
            mail("luilli.guillan@gmail.com", "conexion fallida", "hola");
            echo 'Other error : <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muéstranos tu clase `DbMySQLi` (considera cambiar información sensible por datos ficticios para no revelas tu usuario de BD, contraseña, etc). Hay que ver qué haces en esa clase, si levantas una excepción por ejemplo cuando la conexión falla.

Comment: la clase DbMySQLi no le he hecho yo, viene ya con prestashop y creo que es esta que esta en github: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/db/DbMySQLi.php

Comment: ¿Qué debería ocurrir cuando no hay conexión? Quizá puedes indicar lo que deba hacer el código dentro del bloque `catch`, ahí donde ahora mandas un correo electrónico.

Comment: cuando no hay conexion deberia seguir funcionando normalmente la pagina (ya que es una conexion a una base de datos remota, y no a la base de datos de prestashop, aunque para probarla la pongo a localhost en realidad si pones remotehost la pagina deja de funcionar igualmente). He sustituido el catch por esta linea: `catch (PrestaShopException $ex)` y ahora la pagina carga pero no funcionan los botones de añadir al carrito.